# Apps disappear after restart

Tags: applications, reboot, system-apps

After an android update, my apps disappeared. The apps cannot be seen in the apps list, and they are seen as 'com.something.something' in the settings app manager. Some of the apps are not in the SD Card and even Android System Webview disappears after every restart. Sometimes, my phone randomly restarts and all my apps come back. Please help.

Comment: What is your previous and current Android versions? What are all the list of apps that are disappearing? Add more information that could help answering your question.

Comment: Device brand/model might also help. Also, do all apps "disappear", or only those installed on SD card?

Comment: You should try wiping `cache` in recovery mode, it helps occasionally.

Comment: My device is SM-N9005. I updated from N9005DXUGBOF1 to N9005DXUGBOK3. Apps which disappear are Aznog, Google Street View, Android System Webview, Silly Sausage, Brain Dots, C2HAMPS, MEGA and Psych!.

Comment: I have already tried wiping cache several times but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was a problem with knox, and it fixed itself after i rooted ny phone.